# Smartface in action does not work on android devices

Tags: smartface.io

I have opened smartface in action application on the IDE, but it does not work on android devices. When the application opens just a white and empty page is appeared on the device screen.

And all the objects that must be in the pages in the project are also disappeared.
All the pages have just a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Smarface Emulator takes a lot of memory (I think because all JS files are loaded in the memory). Try to clear (close all apps from) the memory of your Android phone and try again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It does not still work. On the smartface ide, the main page of the smartface in action project is still white. There is no object on the page, so when I emulate the project I just see a white page on the device screen and I cannot do anything due to no object on the page.

Comment: Which device do you use? Also can you please tell what is the android version of that device?